# How to use the local storage only for the current page. in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, local-storage

Is it possible to somehow clear the localStorage value when navigationg away from the current page.

I am trying to save the scrollTop value of the page on a localStorage variable and use it to scroll to that point incase the page is refreshed .

But If I go to Different page I want the localStorage value to be set ot null again .

Is there any easy way I can do it

**UPDATE**

Added the answer provied by `Blaze` to my script and its generating error

Script

```
$(document).on('vclick','#outerPage',function(e){
  // alert('yo i am clickable now'); 
    var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset(); 
   //or $(this).offset(); if you really just want the current element's offset
   var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
   var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
  // localStorage.setItem("scrollPosition", relY);
   //storePosition.topCoordinate = relY; 
  //alert(relY);
    obj = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('scrolls') );
    obj[location.pathname] = relY;
    localStorage.setItem('scrolls', JSON.stringify(obj) ); 
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("scrolls"));
});
```

***ERROR***

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '/url.html' of null
```

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 1):

Yes

just use the unload function with jquery [jquery/unload](http://api.jquery.com/unload/)

On the unload function, just clear the localstorage

```
localStorage.clear();
```

Comment: I tried this also bro but the function is not being called :(. I mean I used unload()

Comment: @Blazemonger but I am not using the layout of the JQuery mobile completely its just normal website with some Jquery css . So when I click on the links it opens different url supposedly your Idea should have worked .

Comment: Maybe just before you open the url, you just clear the localstorage.